# iPhone requesting password for different Apple ID when updating apps after updating iOS

Tags: ios, itunes, ios-appstore

My iPhone 5 was updated to iOS 8.3 with a different computer. Now the apps I downloaded before the updates by computer was made, are now bothering me a lot. Any time I want to update them, my iPhone asks me to enter the password for the Apple ID of that computer I used to update it.

Comment: Then you need to wipe it & go back to your original computer & restore from your own latest backup. You have, by the sound of it, hybridised your device to someone else's ID.

Answer (score 1):

The computer you used to upgrade iOS was apparently signed into a different Apple ID when you upgraded your device. The thing that doesn't make any sense is that the Apple ID signed in on the computer shouldn't matter - you should have to sign-in on the device with a a different Apple ID for it to matter.

That said, you can try signing out of the App Store on the device (App Store app > bottom of the Featured tab > tap on the button that says "Apple ID: xxxx@xxxx" > Sign Out), then sign back in with original Apple ID.